# Enhanced for loop shortcut

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Is the following version of ***for loop*** possible (or a variation thereof fulfilling the purpose of shortening code with one line)?

```
for(String string: stringArray; string.toLowerCase()){
//stuff
 }
```

Instead of

```
for(String string: stringArray){
  string = string.toLowerCase();
  //stuff

 }
```

May seem like a stupid question but that one line is tiresome to write all the time when it applies to every element of the loop.

Comment: No, the first example is not correct syntax. I suggest that you try to compile it. You should get a compiler error.

Comment: Nope, not possible in straight up Java.

Comment: @Code-Guru I am aware ;) was looking for something similar.

Comment: What do you mean by "all the time"? You just type that one line once.

Comment: If you loop through the array multiple times, you should simply create *another* array with all the strings in lower-case then loop through the elements in the new array.

Comment: Every time I have an enhanced for loop where I have to do something to  every object in the loop before doing anything else. It is just a small quirk I have with the loops, it is these small tricks and tips that are fun.

Comment: Does clojure count? (map string/lower-case stringArray). If you really want to type less this is the way to go.

Comment: you wanna write less use haskellllllll

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write it like this

```
for(String string: stringArray)string=string.toLowerCase();
```

This is just as short. Also in a normal for loop `for(int i=0;i<40;i++)` you can use the comma operator to keep everything on one line

Comment: Except that this doesn't do anything. The result of 'toLowerCase()' is ignored.

Comment: Well it's not nit picky because now it's exactly what he had before minus a new line, which IMO makes the code less readable.

Comment: Not arguing with that, but that is exactly what he asked for, to make the code on one line, so that is exactly what I did

Comment: His question literally says "for the purposes of shortening it to one line"

Comment: Yes, but with the condition of not using `string = ...`. I'll take back my -1 for your logical argument. Perhaps you should read the first sentence again. He's actually asking for a variation of the `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you, look I agree there nothing special about my answer, but I definitely didn't give out misinformation or post anything inherently incorrect

Comment: This is actually the answer that keeps it shortest, though I am saddened to find out that what I wanted is not in JavaSE

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's not possible. You could take a look at [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained), which has something like this (Predicates/Closures), but it doesn't help much in improving your code.

Cmpletely offtopic maybe, but it might help, if you would use Groovy, which is fully compatible with Java, it would be something like:

```
String[] stringArray = ["Lower", "Case"] as String[]

stringArray.collect { it.toLowerCase() }.each { item ->
    println item
}
```

Which would print:

- lower
- case

But, like I said, this might not be a viable option in your case.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.

The trick with the enhanced-for loop is that it behaves like any other loop over a collection - you're working with the individual elements *one at a time*, as opposed to all at once.

Furthermore, since `toLowerCase()` returns a new `String`, as it should, it should only be called in situations where it's absolutely needed, as opposed to creating a new variable for that (unless you need it in more places, in which case it's better to move the lower-case functionality into those methods).

Answer (score 0):

You should consider refactoring your code into several methods each with their own loops. One method creates a new array (or list) with transformed elements from the original list (such as applying toLowerCase() to the Strings in an array). The other methods process the new array rather than the original.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible as of now. :)